# Allow specific users to upload files

Tags: php, file-upload, ldap, ldap-query

I am trying to create a form for uploading files to a specific folder on my web-server. I used ldap authentication in conjunction with php to link authenticated users to the upload form. Something like:

```
if($ldap_id=="user") include('upload.html');
```

where "upload.html" would link to a php script for uploading files.

But if somebody accidentally comes upon the upload form, they could also upload to the web-server. How can I stop this from happening?

Comment: `upload.html` would need to be `upload.php`, then just `if($ldap_id != "user") { die("Not Authorized"); }`

Comment: Just add the check to the process-file as well, since you seem to have no control over which files are retrieved by the users. Check for `$ldap_id == "user"` in the upload process, and then execute the upload processing if it exists.

Comment: @AbraCadaver But how to prevent someone from accidentally accessing `upload.php`?

Comment: @junkfoodjunkie I will try that. Thanks!

Comment: If they access it then the `if` will fail and `die()`.  That code needs to be in `upload.php`.

Comment: @AbraCadaver Thanks. That makes sense.